# How can I reduce the RPM of a solar powered motor to 2 RPM?

Tags: dc-motor, solar-cell

This DC motor (RF-500TB-12560) with a plastic gearbox (8 gears) turns at 20 RPM using a 5V 30mA solar panel.

I need this to turn only 2 RPM. What size solar panel will do this?

I make solar powered sculptures and have a lot of people ordering them.  I’m an artist and came up with the idea. I happened to pick the right cell for the original motor. It was pure luck!  Then they ran out of the motor. Since then it’s been trial and error. I have so many different motors and solar cells and I really don’t know what I’m doing.

[image]

Comment: Really what you're looking for is just a 5V tolerant DC motor with a gearbox that turns the full-speed rotation down to 2rpm.  The motor you posted has a nominal rpm of 2100 at 6V supply, that gear box is just stepping it down to the ~20rpm.  Also it appears there's plenty of RF-500TB-12560 at Amazon, 11$ for a 2 pack of just the motor without the gear box.

Comment: It is unlikely that you could "tune" this motor's speed down an additional 10x with a lower power source. The motor is already running at a very low power input. One possibility would be pulsing the motor at a specific rate but this would add a somewhat complex pulse controller (PWM), and may cost you more than the original motor system. The best method may be to find a matching motor and reducer gear set that gives the required 2 RMP's.  If you must use the existing motor you might add an additional low cost gear box, (try Amazon or AliExpress).

Comment: Look for other applications that require the similar low speed and find their suppliers.  BBQ Rotisserie Motor?

Comment: Have someone 3D-print you different gears.  This is a Bendix problem not a Tesla problem.

Answer (score 2):

> This DC motor (RF-500TB-12560) with a plastic gearbox (8 gears) turns
> at 20 RPM using a 5V 30mA solar panel.
>
> I need this to turn only 2 RPM. What size solar panel will do this?

The rotation speed of a permanent magnet DC motor is directly proportional to voltage. So if 5 V makes it go at 20 rpm then 0.5 V should reduce it to 2 rpm. A single solar cell puts out ~0.5 V, so it should be perfect.

However at such low voltage the motor may not have enough torque to overcome friction in the gears and bearings. If the motor won't start on a single cell then you could:-

1. Add gears or pulleys to give a further 10:1 reduction at 5 V.
2. Add a DC motor speed controller to reduce the effective voltage until it runs at the desired speed.
3. Use a different motor and gearbox that does lower rpm on 5 V.
4. A combination of 2 and 3.

A greater gear reduction not only reduces speed but also increases output torque, so the motor may be able to start on a lower voltage. Using a speed controller gives you finer control, but most need at least 5 V to work properly. Some might misoperate if the solar panel doesn't get enough light.

If you want to keep it simple then get a number of solar panels with different voltages, or several single cells and wire them in series to get voltage increments of 0.5 V. Then you can try out your various motors on different voltages to (hopefully) find a combination that produces the right speed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need *exactly* 2 RPM, you will have a hard time achieving that with this motor, especially if you rely on voltage control.

Your best bet with a DC motor is to use PWM control. Rough guess, about 15-30% duty cycle at 100Hz or so would reduce the speed to what you want. Use an LMC555 (CMOS) timer to make this.

Finally, a stepper motor could be used instead. Then you can fix the angular speed to a fixed frequency. This requires a bit of logic (2 flip-flops) and a clock (could be the 555 again.)

Comment: Since it's a sculpture I bet it doesn't have to be *exactly* 2 RPM, just closer to 2 than 20

Comment: and you could use some practice with minimalist designs :) YAGNI principle

Comment: however, you do have a useful point that if the asker wants their motor to consistently spin at the same speed, regardless of the amount of light, some kind of regulator circuit could be used

Comment: Not sure where you’re coming from. Things don’t get much more minimalist than a 555.

Comment: wrapping half the the solar panel in black tape is more minimalist. Bonus points if the sculpture blocks some light from the solar panel so it speeds up and slows down as it rotates

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should have been posted with the question.
The [Mabuchi specification for the RF-500TB-12560 motor](https://product.mabuchi-motor.com/detail.html?id=77) claims operation from 4V - 14V.
The [Amazon page of the same motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NCOFCV7) claims it works from 1.5V - 12V.
So running reliably at 1V or less is not likely, even less likely under a load.

The potential problem with a motor speed controller would be that your power source is solar cells that depend on the sun shining.  Well the sun doesn't shine 100% all day, there's got to be a little rain sometimes, (so I've heard). The controller would most likely lose control or who knows what at reduced voltages (or a small cloud).  Maybe that idea can be re-investigated if you wanted to add something like a battery back up to the system.

However, with a little searching you can often find something that fits your needs nearly exactly.
Here is a low cost 5V 2rpm geared motor assembly from AliExpress:
[CHANCS JS-50 DC Brushed Motor 5V 2RPM](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256803519838054.html?spm=a2g0o.store_pc_allProduct.8148356.17.41ae6c15e0aAAZ&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21USD%21US%20%245.90%21US%20%245.90%21%21%21%21%21%402101f49c16801345220978855e33e8%2112000026874929041%21sh&gatewayAdapt=glo2usa&_randl_shipto=US)

In addition both Amazon and Ebay have very similar motors from the same manufactureer.

Amazon.
[CHANCS Slow Speed Motor JS-50 6V DC 2RPM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B092M597D7)

Ebay
[DC3 5 6 12 24V 2rpm-100rpm](https://www.ebay.com/itm/222718647427?hash=item33db10dc83:g:dosAAOSwEDNiIwhd&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA8BM8u7NYloMKiPMTSj8J%2BjmQBwFMza4V%2BIbRz%2BT5HLOcggEGJx7hdbI%2B9tKwNwefgC529BjLaOkVaOb2FeZdDNWYDHsaEneLlFB9WmNWuqKrdnnbXX8mC5UrpW8ChfRitOgxWpNFH8GIv%2FlP1sF%2B5DUT7tz7DZmhqYInpM1m8kJGCrsZv3VAIwiDymaG3C0KDYFKlztKxA%2Fr6uD%2F%2FmUzLux7%2FLt0M%2BkcgeXz1Ipj8eUVzyYDTZn%2F6VSHYHpg8EzoZxYNv64lUkZwV0dj2NAeupOcTHHNQrogCjnWOmgIm%2F8imY5IYoT54d8NjKTU95R6xw%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABFBMuI_V_eVh)